# Weak Kurepa Hypothesis and eventually different functions

Tags: set-theory

I've recently found myself reading bits of Kanamori and Magidor's "The evolution of large cardinal axioms in set theory." On page 211, they write
"By the weak Kurepa's Hypothesis (wKH) let us mean the assertion that there are functions $\left(f_\alpha \mid \alpha<\omega_2\right) \subseteq {}^{\omega_1}\omega$ which are eventually different, i.e. whenever $\alpha<\beta<\omega_2$ there is a $\gamma_{\alpha \beta}<\omega_1$ so that $f_\alpha(\delta)\neq f_\beta(\delta)$ for $\gamma_{a \beta} \leq \delta<\omega_1$."

In the past, I have seen wKH refer to the existence of a weak Kurepa tree, i.e. a tree of cardinality and height $\omega_1$ with at least $\omega_2$ many cofinal branches. Is there any connection between these two axioms or is this simply a conventions problem of having two different ways of weakening KH?

Comment: If you have this family of eventually different functions, couldn't you look at the tree of their restrictions to ordinals $\eta<\omega_1$, ordered by inclusion? It seems to me that will be a tree like you describe.

Comment: Why does the resulting tree have size $\omega_1$? There is a silly upper bound of $\min(2^{\aleph_0},\aleph_2)$, but I'd rather not assume CH (as then $2^{<\omega_1}$ itself is a weak Kurepa tree).

Comment: You're right, it isn't clear. There are sources which call your first principle the transversal hypothesis (e.g. [this paper by Walker](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274577)), but it also isn't clear to me that their version of wKH has to do with weak Kurepa trees.